# How to keep email layout the same on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, mobile, html-email

I have a flyer that I would like to fit to all screen sizes so it keeps the same layout however on iphones the layout breaks, I'm not sure what I am missing here. The flyer fits in inspection mode on chrome but on litmus it behaves differently, I have attached images for a comparison, below is also a link to the flyer. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

http://dev.hurford-salvi-carr.co.uk/Siavoush/email/new-homes/index.html

current

[image]

desired

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the HTML template you are using purposefully causes the stacking style you are seeing on the iphone (and mobile in general). If you want it so that doesn't happen (so the desktop view is maintained across all devices), you'll want to set your containing table to a fixed width -- I'd suggest 600px. That's assuming I'm understanding your goal though.